# How to create x number of files with perl?

Tags: perl

I want to create a specified number of files ranging from 1..10000000, containing "some text", how do you do this in perl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what's stopping you?  Open the relevant filehandles and do the writing.

Comment: If you're having trouble with homework at least show us what you've tried instead of asking us to just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 my $count = 3;
 for (my $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    open(my $f, ">>file$i.txt") or die("couldn't open file$i.txt");
    print $f "some text";
    close($f); 
 }
```

Comment: how about using Perl? `foreach my $i (1..$count) { open( my $fh, '>', "file$i.txt") or die "cannot create file$i.txt: $!"; print {$fh} "some text"; close $fh; }`

Comment: lets teach her proper Perl: C-style for and unnecessary use of ${i} are confusing, but 2 args open, bareword filehandles and no error checking, that's wrong.

Comment: I still like my c-style for, but your other remarks are totally right. updated

Comment: a couple more fixes to go: 3 argument open, and displaying $! in the error message, and you'll be done ;--)

Answer (score 3):

You do this the same way you'd do it in any other language.  Break down the job into a series of small steps that you can implement:

- A loop around:
- Opening a file and writing the text to it.

So you might have code like:

```
my $count = 0;
while( $count < 10000 )
{
    open(my $fh, '>', "output.$count") 
      or die "Failed to open file: $!";
    print $fh "sometext\n";
    close( $fh );

    $count += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: you can actually use `foreach my $i (1..100000) {...` here, perl takes care of not preallocating the list for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could create 10 million files in one directory, it is inadvisable since looking around that directory will prove troublesome.  ls won't return for hours, bash auto-complete on file names will hang, and in general you will need to kill your terminal to use it again.

Consider partitioning the files across multiple directories.  You can use md5, sha1, modulo some number(s), groups of n-digits in the filename, etc. to achieve the partitioning.  Keeping the total number of files in any directory less than a few thousand is preferable.

Here's an example using md5:

```
use File::Path qw( make_path );
use Digest::MD5 qw( md5_hex );

use constant DIRECTORY_ROOT => '/path/where/you/want/these/files';
use constant FILE_SEP       => '/';
use constant MAX_FILES      => 10;

for my $count ( 1 .. MAX_FILES ) {
    my $subdir = substr( md5_hex($count), 0, 2 );    # First 2 characters

    my $dir = join FILE_SEP, DIRECTORY_ROOT, $subdir;
    make_path( $dir );
    my $file = join FILE_SEP, $dir, $count;

    open( my $fh, '>', $file )
        or die "Failed to open file $file : $!";
    print $fh "some text\n";
    close($fh);
}
```

This will create the following set of files:

```
./c9
./c9/8
./16
./16/6
./ec
./ec/3
./c8
./c8/2
./e4
./e4/5
./a8
./a8/4
./d3
./d3/10
./8f
./8f/7
./45
./45/9
./c4
./c4/1
```